# How to deploy laravel websocket on GCP Standard App Engine?

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, websocket, laravel-websockets

I am using laravel 6 and I want to deploy laravel based websocket server using supervisor on google cloud standard app engine platform.

I am using this package:
beyondcode/laravel-websockets

I have setup everything and everything is working fine on local machine!
What is the exact procedure to follow to deploy it on GCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, WebSockets are not supported by App Engine Standard. There is work being done with Cloud Run support for WebSockets, so this situation might be changing in the future for App Engine Standard.

[Cloud Run WebSockets and gRPC bi-directional streaming support](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#grpc_websocket)

To use WebSockets today, use App Engine Flexible or switch to another service such as Compute Engine.

[Creating Persistent Connections with WebSockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity)

[Google Compute Engine WebSocket Support](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#websocket_support)

Comment: so what are the steps to setup laravel websocket on google cloud engine flex env?

Comment: @RuchitParikh - I provided you with a link. Which part is confusing and needs further clarification?

Comment: I am doing this for the first time! still didn't get much!
i did created supervisor file
and added firewall rule 
nginx is not added though is it required and how do i configure it for laravel?
my websocket port is 6001!

Comment: @RuchitParikh - Close this question. Create a new question, show your work, and explain the details of your new problem.

Comment: Ok this is the new problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330279/how-do-i-setup-websocket-on-gcp-flex-environment